# Shadow does not work with round corner on top Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hello in my condition i am using two conditions ,one to make round corner only top view after that shadow on the top only , only one condition works if i am adding code for shadow it does not work but i remove corner code then shadow works please guide me

for round corner i am using this extension

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
}
```

and for shadow

```
func shadowToUIView( uiview : UIView){
    uiview.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    uiview.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.50
    uiview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    uiview.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    uiview.layer.shouldRasterize = false
}
```

and in cell for row i am using this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
    cell.firstView.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft,.topRight], radius: 25.0)
    shadowToUIView(uiview: cell.firstView)
    HomeMenu.openMenuCard(cell:cell, indexPath:indexPath, firstViewMain:firstViewMain, openedTab: openedTab)
    return cell
}
```

after adding replied code

[image]

Comment: A picture is much appretiated to under stand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I experience the same behaviour (XCode10.3, simulator IOS12.4). Doc states : "The layer’s alpha channel determines how much of the layer’s content and background shows through. Fully or partially opaque pixels allow the underlying content to show through, but fully transparent pixels block that content.
The default value of this property is nil. When configuring a mask, remember to set the size and position of the mask layer to ensure it is aligned properly with the layer it masks." Did you check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the method that will allow you to make the `UIView` round with shadow:

```
extension UIView {
  func addShadow(cornerRadius: CGFloat, maskedCorners: CACornerMask, color: UIColor, offset: CGSize, opacity: Float, shadowRadius: CGFloat) {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    self.layer.maskedCorners = maskedCorners
    self.layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = offset
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
    self.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
  }
}
```

**Use:**
For rounding all the corners:

```
<your_view_object>.addShadow(cornerRadius: 10.0, maskedCorners: [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner], color: AppColors.themeBlack.withAlphaComponent(0.6), offset: CGSize.zero, opacity: 0.4, shadowRadius: 4.0)
```

For rounding only top corners:

```
<your_view_object>.addShadow(cornerRadius: 10.0, maskedCorners: [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner], color: AppColors.themeBlack.withAlphaComponent(0.6), offset: CGSize.zero, opacity: 0.4, shadowRadius: 4.0)
```

For rounding only bottom corners:

```
<your_view_object>.addShadow(cornerRadius: 10.0, maskedCorners: [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner], color: AppColors.themeBlack.withAlphaComponent(0.6), offset: CGSize.zero, opacity: 0.4, shadowRadius: 4.0)
```

For making the shadow as per you requirement change the others parameters.

Comment: bro i don't no why but it is working for some views not for all

Comment: This code not working for those view. make sure you are not using `.layer.maksToBouns = true` or `.clipSubViews = true`. Make them as false. 
And one more thing make sure if the `view` on that you are appyling the shadow and corner both, having superView then make the superview's `.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`.

Then It should work fine.

Comment: is this a table view?

Comment: then make the table view `.backgroundColor` and `cell.ceontentView.backgroundColor` clear as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198989/discussion-between-bestiosdeveloper-and-shahzad-ali).

Comment: Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Doc for layer.mask states:
"The layer’s alpha channel determines how much of the layer’s content and background shows through. Fully or partially opaque pixels allow the underlying content to show through, but fully transparent pixels block that content. The default value of this property is nil. When configuring a mask, remember to set the size and position of the mask layer to ensure it is aligned properly with the layer it masks."

So, I added

```
    mask.frame = self.bounds.offsetBy(dx: -6.0, dy: -6.0)
```

Works correctly (need to adapt offset values).

Answer (score 0):

Good Question..!!!
I have same requirement in my recent school application.Here's 
Best solutions which will working as per your requirement.
Please use below **ShadowView** class for rounded shadow.

https://ibb.co/3S0rD7s

https://ibb.co/qCtrGqz

```
class ShadowView:UIView{[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    private var theShadowLayer: CAShapeLayer?
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
            let rounding = CGFloat.init(10.0)
            var shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()
            shadowLayer.name = "ShadowLayer1"
            shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: rounding).cgPath
            shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
            shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.init(red: 60.0/255.0, green: 64.0/255.0, blue: 67.0/255.0, alpha:0.3).cgColor
            shadowLayer.shadowRadius = CGFloat.init(2.0)
            shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = Float.init(0.5)
            shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 0.0, height: 1.0)
            if  let arraySublayer1:[CALayer] = self.layer.sublayers?.filter({$0.name == "ShadowLayer1"}),let sublayer1 =  arraySublayer1.first{
                    sublayer1.removeFromSuperlayer()
            }
            self.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, below: nil)
            shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()
            shadowLayer.name = "ShadowLayer2"
            shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: rounding).cgPath
            shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            shadowLayer.shadowPath = shadowLayer.path
            shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.init(red: 60.0/255.0, green: 64.0/255.0, blue: 67.0/255.0, alpha:0.15).cgColor
            shadowLayer.shadowRadius = CGFloat.init(6.0)
            shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = Float.init(0.5)
            shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
            if  let arraySublayer2:[CALayer] = self.layer.sublayers?.filter({$0.name == "ShadowLayer2"}),let sublayer2 =  arraySublayer2.first{
                sublayer2.removeFromSuperlayer()
            }
            self.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, below: nil)

    }
}
```

**Easy to implement**
Simple design make One Containerview inheritance of class ShadowView And add Sub container view (rounded corner view)..That’s it..!!!..Run it..!!